# ASP.NET Custom Error Pages

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-7, web-config

I have custom error pages setup in my ASP.Net 4.0 application. I would like to have it ignore 404s from images. I am getting error e-mails pertaining the 404 page getting image urls sent to it. Is that possible?

```
        <error redirect="http://***/404-Error/" statusCode="404" />
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are the emails being generated?

Comment: Is this in `<system.web>` or in `<system.webServer>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store images in separate directory and create in that directory web.config with different error handling routine.